# jquery widget multiple calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, multiple-instances

I have created a widget in jquery and calling it from cshtml. On first call widget is created successfully and data is shown properly. But when the widget is called 2nd time it does not hit the "_create" function of widget. Why is it so?
Do I need to destroy the widget prior to create it again or should I initialize it first and then create it separately. If yes then please tell me how to do so?

This is my widget sample code.

```
$.widget("namespace.widgetname", {

//These are default options
options: {
    Name: ""
},

//Triggers when widget called
_create: function () {
console.log($(this.element));
},
_destroy: function () {
    this.element.remove();
} 
})
```

widget is being called on button click like this.

```
function Preview() {
$("#targetdiv").widgetname({
        Name: $('#txtAdminNameLeader').val()
    });
}
```

So, in short, multiple calls are not triggering on widget call.

*ANY HELP WILL BE HIGHLY APPRECIATED* as I am stuck here for 3 days :(
Thanks

Comment: I suspect the widget factory checks whether the widget has already been initialized on an element, and doesn't repeat it.

Comment: If you want to change options, you have to destroy the widget and initialize it again, or use `.widgetname("option", "Name", $('#txtAdminNameLeader').val())`.

Comment: hi @Barmar thanks for reply.

actually the problem is not in changing options(thats what i know how to change :P) but i want to call the _create function of widget multiple times which is not happening. the widget is being called on button click.

Comment: and yes i want to call widget on an element repeatedly.

Comment: You have to destroy the widget before you can create it again.

Comment: i am destroying widget like this
    $('#targetdiv')['widgetname']('destroy');

it destroy it but even then it does not hit the _create function again.
:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to use _destory function to destroy the widget. you need to call "destroy" explicitly like:

```
$("#targetdiv").widgetname("destroy");
```

then you can call widget again and it will most definitely hit the _create.

```
$("#targetdiv").widgetname({
    Name: $('#txtAdminNameLeader').val()
});
```

also you can do it in single line as follows:

```
$("#targetdiv").widgetname({
    Name: $('#txtAdminNameLeader').val()
}).widgetname("destroy");
```

this destory will only destroy the memory object. do whatever you want to do in _create of widget.
hope that your problem will be solved. :)